# Magento Quick Search

Tags: php, html, forms, magento

I am having a small problem with the Magento quick search. When I search in the box say

`ice machine`

Then everything will be retuernd where it has `ice` or `machine` in the title. I need it so it would just search products with the exact string `ice machine` in the title.

I found out if I put `"ice machine"` with the double speech marks it will return only products names that match that exactly.

So I need a way so that the double speech marks get added around the search query automaticlly so it will search the full text not both words seperatly.

Is there a way to do this in the form HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is covered over in the MagentoCommerce forums multiple times. The Like search logic was changed from AND to OR. For it to give better results, it needs to be changed back to AND so all items in the search query must match.

[Search Logic Fix](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/213559/#t287566)

In **app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Mysql4/Fulltext.php** find the class `public function prepareResult($object, $queryText, $query)`

The following piece of code:

```
if ($like) {
    $likeCond = '(' . join(' OR ', $like) . ')';
}
```

needs to be

```
if ($like) {
    $likeCond = '(' . join(' AND ', $like) . ')';
}
```

Create your own rewrite module to overwrite just this class or do an override by copying the whole file Fulltext.php over to **app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Mysql4/Fulltext.php** and modifying **OR** to **AND**. The module is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Using the form you can do that using javascript, but you would have to watch out if the customer enters double quotes himself already.
My suggestion would be to rewrite the `Mage_CatalogSearch_Helper_Data` helper and override the `getQueryText()` method. There you can quote existing quotes and add your own quotes around the query.

Comment: Im not sure how to do this can you help me through it?

Comment: There are many sources of information on how to rewrite a Magento helper (or model or block). It's beyond the scope of this question, but if you want to learn how to effectively customize Magento you **need** to know that. Check out http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento for an excellent introduction by Alan Storm.