# How to override search and suggest in Magento?

Tags: magento, search, magento-1.7

I want to modify the query sent by Magento search form (trim zeros, remove hyphens, etc).
What methods do i have to override to get it work in magento search, suggest and advanced search?
(Im using magento CE 1.7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i finally did was to rewrite Mage_CatalogSearch_Helper_Data and override getQueryText()  as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11308076/594323

Answer (score 1):

Start at the place where the search forms `POST`:

1. [`Mage_CatalogSearch_ResultController::indexAction()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/ResultController.php#L44)
2. [`Mage_CatalogSearch_AdvancedController::resultAction()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/AdvancedController.php#L44)

Within each of these methods, you can follow the chain through the respective search collections, e.g.:

- `Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Advanced_Result::_getProductCollection()`

  - `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Advanced::getProductCollection()`

    - And so on...